# Is there any reason to use \hypersetup in preamble immediately after loading hyperref?

Tags: hyperref

Is there any reason to use `\hypersetup` in preamble immediately after `\usepackage{hyperref}`? (or is `\hypersetup` only intended for later use far from package load)

Is there any difference between putting options in `\hypersetup` at loadtime versus with `\hypersetup`?
ie:

```
\usepackage[someoption=true] {hyperref}
```

versus

```
\usepackage[] {hyperref}
\hypersetup{someoption=true}
```

**Why Ask?**  Lyx does the latter, and I think it is probably a bug, and it should do the former. Am I right?: https://www.lyx.org/trac/ticket/10319

Answer (score 7):

- There are options, that are needed at package loading time (`\usepackage`), which cannot be used later (examples: driver options, `hyperindex`, `hyperfootnotes`, `bookmarks`, `implicit`, `pdfa`, `pdfversion`).
- Package `hyperref` usually warns, if an option is set, which is already consumed by `hyperref` and the setting of the value will not have an effect anymore.
- LaTeX expands the options of a package, which can be fatal for the macros in option values for the PDF information entries (`pdfauthor`, `pdftitle`, `pdfsubject`, `pdfkeywords`). Therefore, its is recommended to set these keys after the package loading:

  ```
  \usepackage{hyperref}
  \hypersetup{
    pdfauthor={Me},
    pdftitle={Title with macros, ...},
    % ...,
  }
  ```